# load dropdown with mysql data

Tags: php

Hi a newbie here and much appreciate your help on the following matter.

I need to make a dynamic dropdown which contains SQL data. my database has three columns, cheque starting number, ending number and number of cheque leafs. Also it has three data sets respectively under starting cheque number 200,310,401 and ending numbers 205,315,422 and cheque leafs 6,6,22.

I need the drop down containing all the numbers between 200 to 205 and 310 to 315 and 401 to 422.

Please help with me a sample code since I'm have no clue as to how this data can be extracted from database.

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you.

Example Code :

```
  <?php
      $query="select `name`,`age`,`sex` from person;"; //query to extract results from database
      $result=mysql_query($query);
      $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
   ?>
   <select name="dyndrop">
         <option><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>   // Displaying results
         <option><?php echo $row['age'];?></option>
         <option><?php echo $row['sex'];?></option>
   </select>
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! Much appreciate your support. I can do more now on the same lines. Thanks again